# Redirecting java System.out.println to file in jruby

Tags: java, logging, io, jruby

My Ruby (JRuby) app loads a couple of Java libraries (not maintained by my team) and in those Java librares there are a few System.out.println that are outputting on my app.

In the Ruby side I have redirected STDOUT and STDERR to a log file and I would like to also have the ones coming from Java layer to also output to my file.

Any ideas how I can achieve this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redirect System.out and System.err by using the System.setOUt() and System.setErr() methods. They both take a PrintStream.

Take a look at : https://blogs.oracle.com/nickstephen/entry/java_redirecting_system_out_and

Comment: Thanks, I had this issue recently and this answer got me on the right track. See [my blog post](http://succinctsoftware.com/2015/06/09/redirecting-java-stdout-from-jruby/) for a little more detail on how I solved it.